# How to replace target with label while displaying metrics on grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, telegraf

I have configured telegraf/prometheus/grafana to display system metrics, but now what i want to do is to set up variables in Grafana to display label instead of target which i configured in prometheus.yml file.

[image: prometheus.yml]
[image: grafana variable]
[image: grafana instance]

So my question is how can i replace this **localhost:9126** with **test** without losing all of the metrics, because when i tried Query `label_values(system_uptime, name)`, i got no metrics to show on graphs, so can somebody help me, and show me how to do it right? Thanks.

Comment: run the system_uptime query in prometheus and see if you get name as test in it?

Comment: @AmjadHussainSyed no i am not getting name as test.
https://prnt.sc/rmfvn8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try like this? or you can use `host` label which is discovered by telegraf automatically. I'm not sure of your requirement.

```
- job_name: telegraf
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9126']
    labels:
      name: test
```

and in your `grafana`

```
label_values(system_uptime, name)
```

or if you want to use host(depends on your requirement)

```
label_values(system_uptime, host)
```

Comment: I have tried with both `label_values(system_uptime, name)` and `label_values(system_uptime, host)` but in that case i don't get any data to show on the graph for both **CPU** and **Memory**. I want is to show the **name** instead of **instance** here but keep the same functionality, so basically only to change **display name** for **instance**. Why i'm doing this, is because i have connected multiple servers remotely to Prometheus, which already have their own names, and when i select **instance** from that dropdown https://prnt.sc/rmimev, i want to see server names instead of their ip:port.

Comment: I applied this to the case that i described and it works, i had to add new variable `$name`, and i can do selection of different servers by that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Regex` field to extract some part of the values:

[image]